# Error: <circle> attribute cx: Expected length, "NaN" and Error: <circle> attribute cy: Expected length, "NaN"

Tags: d3.js

This is my code

```
// Importing CSV file
d3.csv("Dataset.csv", function (error, data) {

    //output error if csv file failed to load
    if(error){
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        console.log(data); //show loaded data to console



        //linear scaling the datasets.
        var xscale = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([d3.min(function (d) {
                return d.Surface_temperature;
            }), d3.max(function (d) {
                return d.Surface_temperature;
            })])
            .range([0, w - 100]);

        var yscale = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([d3.min(function (d) {
                return d.habitable_temperature;
            }), d3.max(function (d) {
                return d.habitable_temperature;
            })])
            .range([h - 200, 0]);



        // appended svg with its attributes inside the body element
        var mysvg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width",w)
            .attr("height",h);


        // appending svg circle elements
        mysvg.selectAll("circle")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("cx", function (d) {
            return xscale(d.Surface_temperature);
        })
        .attr("cy", function (d) {
            return yscale(d.habitable_temperature);
        })
        .attr("r", 10)

    }

});
```

I am getting Error:  attribute cx: Expected length, "NaN" please help me. I have tried to check almost everywhere but couldn't solve this.

Comment: Sounds like bad data in your csv file -- or your have mismatched column names. Is one column really capitalized ("Surface_temperature") while the other is not ("habitable_temperature")?

Comment: no the column names are exactly the same in the dataset which i took them from. thank you for your concern. my issue is now resolved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not using [`d3.min`](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/master/README.md#min) and [`d3.max`](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/master/README.md#max) correctly.

Both these functions take the data to calculate the minimum and maximum over, as well as an optional accessor function.  You are only passing an accessor function.

Your scales should be set up as follows (note that I am passing `data` to `d3.min` and `d3.max`):

```
    var xscale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([d3.min(data, function (d) {
            return d.Surface_temperature;
        }), d3.max(data, function (d) {
            return d.Surface_temperature;
        })])
        .range([0, w - 100]);

    var yscale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([d3.min(data, function (d) {
            return d.habitable_temperature;
        }), d3.max(data, function (d) {
            return d.habitable_temperature;
        })])
        .range([h - 200, 0]);
```

Incidentally, to make it easier for others to help you in future, please also provide a sample data file.  It doesn't have to be a real file with thousands of rows, just a simple one with about three rows will do.  To reproduce your problem I made up a test file, but of course I have assumed that there isn't a problem with your data file.

Comment: Yes you are exactly right. i missed to pass the data to d3.min and d3.max. Thank you very much for your help.